# Phaser: InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, error-handling, phaser-framework, game-development

I am using the [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) framework for game development, but while working on it I face a bug which is annoying, I have the following message:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

[image]

The consequence is that because of it I now cannot move my hero, I need to first click once on the phaser window and then it worked, so I tried to debug it, and even by using the default phaser demo the same error message appear and cause the same but, so i concluded that my code is not the problem.

Do you please have any idea? Is there a way to know how to fix it ? Otherwise  how can have more details about it in the console?

***Note: if you wanna download the official starting tutorial to reproduce the error:***

1. Download `.zip`: [here](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/phaser3-tutorial-src.zip)
2. Beginner Tutorial: [here](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/index)

Comment: I also have this error using Firefox, v3.16.2. 

Within `phaser.js` on line `92953` it references: `console.log.apply(console, args);`

Comment: @AdamInTheOculus Hello Sir ! I will delete this post soon because another one is open here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167945/phaser-invalidstateerror please feel free to follow/or upvote this one if you are interested, thank you!